# How to solve a guess-the-number game with a random() function that outputs a segment fault error?

Tags: c

C learner here.

I've made a program that generates a random number that receives input for the user to guess the number. 
When I try to write the code this way:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int random(){
    int num = random();
    return num; 
}

int main(){
    int guess;

    printf("I have a number, try guess it!");
    scanf("%d", &guess);

    if(guess == random()){
        printf("Your answer was correct!");
    }
    else{
        printf("Your answer was not correct!");
    }  

}
```

My compiler gives a `Segment fault` error.

But when I write the program like this, it compiles and runs with no error.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int guess;
    int number = random();

    printf("I have a number, try guess it! \n");
    scanf("%d", &guess);

    if(guess == number){
        printf("Your answer was correct!");
    }
    else{
        printf("Your answer was not correct!");
    }  
}
```

Can somebody tell me how to fix the `segment fault` error I mentioned above? Or how I can write this code properly? Any help is appreciated! <3

In case somebody asks about my system environment, I am using Windows 10 and a online compiler from this website: https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler

Comment: You are doing recursion in the first one. So you're just infinitely doing recursion until you seg fault.

Answer (score 2):

In the function random() you have written in the first code, the line

```
int num = random()
```

is again calling the random function which in turns calls random again and it will result in an infinite loop which might leads to segmentation fault.

So change the function name to some other name like "random_number_generator".

And also avoid using the function names which are already present keywords or inbuilt function names.

Comment: This answer is correct. Did you mean `int num = rand()` rather than `int num = random()`, perchance? If so, you should #include <stdlib.h>. (*Strictly* speaking, the include isn't necessary for rand(), but only because it happens to match the default function prototype, which is the sort of arcana you shouldn't be relying on when learning the language. As a general rule, always include the appropriate headers.)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the second one:

```c
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int guess;
    int number = random();

    printf("I have a number, try guess it! \n");
    scanf("%d", &guess);

    if(guess == number){
        printf("Your answer was correct!");
    }
    else{
        printf("Your answer was not correct!");
    }  
}
```

When this compiles, even through online gdb, you should see: `main.c:13:18: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘random’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]`.

The reason for this is `random` comes from `<stdlib.h>`. You can find this by doing `man random` if you have `man`, otherwise you can check here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man0/stdlib.h.0p.html.

Under it you can see the deceleration `long random(void)`. So the reason the second one works is you are using the `random` function from `stdlib.h` and implicitly declaring it since you aren't explicitly including that library (which you should).

The reason the first doesn't work is because you are using recursion, which I'm assuming you're not meaning to do. If you're new to programming you may be unfamiliar with that term, but basically it means you are calling the same function from within the function itself. You have no stopping criteria, so it continues until it would cause a stack overflow, resulting in a seg fault.

When you do:

```c
int random(){
    int num = random(); // who do I call? stdlib or myself? it's me.
    return num; 
}
```

C doesn't know that the outer `random` is different than the `random` called within it. To change this, you need to rename the outer function like so:

```c
int my_random_func(){
    int num = random(); // calls the stdlib random implicitly
    return num; 
}
```

This is a good reason to also explicitly `#include <stdlib.h>`, so you don't implicitly use a function you aren't trying to.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
int my_random_func(){
    int num = random(); // calls the stdlib random explicitly
    return num; 
}
```

When you explicitly use the headers you need, you can get better failures as well:

```c
#include <stdlib.h> // explicitly state I want the stdlib header.
int random(){
    int num = random(); // which do I call? There is my declaration and stdlib's...
    return num; 
}
```

This results in the following error message:

```
main.c:12:5: error: conflicting types for ‘random’
 int random(void) {
     ^~~~~~
In file included from main.c:10:0:
/usr/include/stdlib.h:321:17: note: previous declaration of ‘random’ was here
 extern long int random (void) __THROW;
                 ^~~~~~
```

Hopefully this helps you see why yours isn't working and why you should try your best to explicitly include headers you are looking for.

Comment: That was really helpful, Thanks!